# Different zgrep output from command line and bash script

Tags: bash, grep

I have a bash script with that loops through lines of a file (`a.txt`) containing paths to a list of gzipped files and searches for phrases in each of those files using `zgrep`.

My bash script is:

```
for i in $(cat $1); do
  echo $i;
  echo zgrep -E '"phrase1|phrase2|phrase3|phrase4|phrase5|phrase6"' $i;
  zgrep -E '"phrase1|phrase2|phrase3|phrase4|phrase5|phrase6"' $i;
done
```

which I call by `myscript.sh a.txt`:

The output is:

```
zgrep -E "phrase1|phrase2|phrase3|phrase4|phrase5|phrase6" myzippedfile.1.gz
phrase2     48      48.00   48
phrase3     35      35.00   35
phrase4     67      67.00   67
phrase5     99      99.00   99
```

(repeated for each file listed in `a.txt`).

**However**, when I execute the `zgrep` command that is being executed inside the scripts for loop, I get a different output.

Executing:

```
zgrep -E "phrase1|phrase2|phrase3|phrase4|phrase5|phrase6" myzippedfile.1.gz
```

at the command line yields:

```
phrase1      29      29.00   29
phrase2      48      48.00   48
phrase3      35      35.00   35
phrase4      67      67.00   67
phrase5      99      99.00   99
phrase6      54      54.00   54
```

This output is correct, whereas the output generated from the bash script for loop is **missing** the first and last lines. How can this be?

*Does anyone see any issues in my bash script?* **Why would the first and last lines be missing from the output?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and last elements in your alternatives contain literal `"` characters. So you'll only match `phrase1` if there's a `"` before it, and only match `phrase6` if there's a `"` after it. You shouldn't have those double quotes in the pattern, it should be:

```
zgrep -E 'phrase1|phrase2|phrase3|phrase4|phrase5|phrase6' $i;
```

You don't have the extra quotes when you execute the `zgrep` command by hand.

Comment: Ah yes! I'm pretty new to bash scripting so this really helped me out. Thanks!